# How to implement hlda transformation to find correlation of topics in gensim?

Tags: python, gensim, topic-modeling

I am trying to categorize the blog content using Topic Modeling. Using LDA transformation, I couldn't find the correlation b/w topics. Say, cricket is a sub topic of Sports topic. However, I come to know that it could be achieved using HLDA. Could some one help me how to implement the HLDA transformation in python gensim package?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a python implementation of hLDA, and gensim currently does not have hLDA as one of its models. You might want to look at C [implementation](https://github.com/blei-lab/hlda) from Blei Lab and Java [implementation](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/api/cc/mallet/topics/HierarchicalLDA.html) in Mallet.

Confusion Note: gensim does have Hierarchical Dirichlet Process implemented - this is distinct from hLDA and, despite the name, will not help you get topic hierarchy.

Comment: is there any python implementation  !!